# Closed mesh cutting and Parameterization

Tags: 3d

I tried to find library that can cut closed mesh for mesh Parameterization,can you suggest the library? or you can provide some algorithms about mesh cutting,Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, any closed surface can be decomposed in several "pair of pants". That is called "pants decomposition".

The following paper shows how each pant can be mapped to two hexagons for surface parameterization:

"Surface matching using consistent pants decomposition":
https://www.ece.lsu.edu/xinli/Research/XinLi_PantsDecomposition.pdf